# Fixing PVC pipe connection leaking from downspout

Tags: leak, pvc, downspout

I was doing some construction and while trying to figure out where the PVC pipe that brings water from the gutters away from my home was going to, I messed up a connection/joint in that pipe. Some plastic came off really easily, and some water started to come out.

I was surprised by the water coming out because it hasn't rained for days, which then made me think that the pipe might be clogged and water is accumulated in the pipe itself. So my question is:

- What is the best course of action here? Should I first get the pipe cleaned (by hydrojetting/snaking it), and then fix the pipe? If so, how do I fix a leaking PVC pipe joint that is wet?

Here is a picture of the watery joist:

[image]

Comment: Minor nit pic: [Joist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joist) vs [joint](https://www.pvcworkshop.com/pipe-joints/). You're working with a "joint" here, not a "joist".

Comment: Oh, you are right! Thanks Freeman. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a down spout, it it leaks rain water will get into the ground, this is usually not a calamity, you could just wrap in in something and then than zip-tie it down.

Attempting any kind of chemical assisted repair on an underwater pipe is tricky, so yeah you need to get rid of the water

How to fix a wet pipe?  dry it first.

Dig deeper so you can use a bucket or pump to lower the water level to below the pipe, dry the pipe using air and/or towels, sawdust, etc then repair.
this is going to work better if the pipe is empty. so yeah unblock it.

Comment: Thanks Jasen! That was my thinking. In fact, I don't even know where the end of the pipes goes to, so it might just be going to the ground itself, close to where is leaking. Could you clarify what do you suggest in terms of "wrap it up in something". What is something?

Lastly, in your last paragraph, when you say "repair", do you refer to the wrap up + zip tie, or there is a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Have to agree. If some more rainwater gets into the ground, it's likely not a calamity. Especially if this isn't right next to the foundation, but somewhere in the middle of the yard.

Answer (score 0):

It is good time to clean the clog.

Glueing it together would be tricky in wet dirty conditions.

Since it is not a pressure pipe you could use a rubber clamp or even rubber coupling.

[image: clamp]

Comment: Thanks! In order to do the rubber coupling, I would need to remove the joist altogether, right? So I could fit the tube in.

Comment: It appears to me that the pipe goes uphill from there to the outlet!

Comment: @Nobita Depending on the situation, choose a rubber clamp or coupling. Hope you are satisfied with my answer.